# Why does this work? Using cin to read to a char array smaller than given input

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cin

I'm reading C++ Primer Plus (6th Edition) and I've come across some sample code in chapter 4 which I have a question about:

Listing 4.2 **strings.cpp**

```
// strings.cpp -- storing strings in an array
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // for the strlen() function
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const int Size = 15;
    char name1[Size]; // empty array
    char name2[Size] = "C++owboy"; // initialized array
    // NOTE: some implementations may require the static keyword
    // to initialize the array name2
    cout << "Howdy! I'm " << name2;
    cout << "! What's your name?\n";
    cin >> name1;
    cout << "Well, " << name1 << ", your name has ";
    cout << strlen(name1) << " letters and is stored\n";
    cout << "in an array of " << sizeof(name1) << " bytes.\n";
    cout << "Your initial is " << name1[0] << ".\n";
    name2[3] = '\0'; // set to null character
    cout << "Here are the first 3 characters of my name: ";
    cout << name2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code itself doesn't cause any confusion, but I've been running it through and I'm confused by a certain scenario.

name1 is initialised as an array of chars 15 elements in length - am I right in thinking this should hold a string 14 characters in length? The end char should be reserved for the string terminator, right?

If I enter my name as **HowCanIPossiblyFitThisEntireStringIn?**, I get the following output:

> Howdy! I'm C++owboy! What's your name?
>
> HowCanIPossiblyFitThisEntireStringIn?
>
> Well, HowCanIPossiblyFitThisEntireStringIn?, your name has 37 letters and is stored
>
> in an array of 15 bytes.
>
> Your initial is H.
>
> Here are the first 3 characters of my name: C++

How is the entire name I enter being stored? If I step through the code, after cin reads into name1, Visual Studio tells me it contains elements 0 - 14, with the last one being the char 'y' ("HowCanIPossibly...). I would assume from this that any extra data entered had been truncated and lost, but this is obviously not the case as the following cout successfully writes the entire name out to the console.

For curiosity's sake, could anyone enlighten me as to what's happening here? For the record, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are writing past the bounds of the array. The C++ standard doesn't say this should be an error; it says it is undefined behaviour. This means anything can happen, including seemingly working correctly. Simply put, your code does not have well-defined behaviour and so you shouldn't trust it to work.

We can imagine why it's probably working though. The first 15 characters will fit nicely into the array:

```
|H|o|w|C|a|n|I|P|o|s|s|i|b|l|y|F|i|t|T|h|i|s|E|n|t|i|r|e|S|t|r|i|n|g|I|n|?|...
^                             ^
|    These characters fit     |
         in the array
```

The rest of the characters are being written to the following memory locations. Now, remember that the null character, which is used to terminate C-style strings, is defined to have a representation that is all 0 bits. Now if the location following the location that contains the `?` has all 0 bits in it, the string will appear to be null-terminated.

But the fact is, this is undefined. It just happens to work. Unfortunately, this is the scariest type of bug because it can seemingly work for a long time until one day you start getting calls from your very, very angry client.

Comment: +1 This is first time i see `undefined behaviour` to be working though. :)

Comment: @scones - It is actually *looks like it is working*, which is the worst kind. It will crash and burn as soon as an important customer shows up.

Comment: @scones In typical implementations, writing past the end of an array simply overwrites the next variable in the stack frame. Unless that variable is a pointer, or you do it to the last variable and overwrite the stack frame header, it's not likely to cause an exception.

Comment: @Barmar If i understand this correctly, this would lead to a buffer overflow and could be exploited.

Comment: @scones Definitely. A hacker could input some string that writes to a certain memory location known to perform some specific role. For example, if a banking application asks you for your name, they might try entering `John Doelalalal$1,000,000,000` (obviously not a realistic example - they're unlikely to store values as text).

Comment: @scones Yes, this is how buffer overflow exploits occur. This is one reason why `string` is preferred over char arrays in C++.

Comment: Very clear, thank you! So if I had another variable defined somewhere and it was allocated in memory directly after name1, what I entered would start altering that variable too (whether it be an int, a class I wrote, or whatever?), and potentially many others depending on how long I'd decided to enter my name as?

Comment: @Rich Yes, I'm sure you can come up with an example that actually demonstrates that.

Comment: I'm surprised `operator>>` isn't overloaded for arrays. I mean, how hard would it be to implement `template<typename T, size_t N> istream_type& operator>>(istream_type& is, T (&array)[N])`?  Implementation would be fairly simple and easy. Read T's until there's no more, and set failbit if there's more.  Oh, how I hate undefined/unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) with the buffer and the size of the buffer:

```
cin.get(name1, Size);
```

As others have noted, it's far easier to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string name1;
cin >> name;
```