# Dynamically input 2d character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic

I'm trying to input a sequence of words using character array. I don't want to use string from STL. Where am I going wrong?

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter the number of words:";
cin>>n;
char **s = new char*[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  char *s = new char[10];
  cin>>s[i];

}
```

Comment: You'll benefit greatly by using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of managing the memory yourself. Something like `std::vector<std::vector<char>>(n, std::vector<char>(10))`. If you are storing strings `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>(n)`

Comment: `I don't want to use string from STL`  Any reason why?

Comment: Just beacuse I want to learn how it would work with char.

Comment: I also think you should be using Vector.

Comment: @lostboy_19 `Just beacuse I want to learn how it would work with char`  So if you want to learn, look at the thousands of examples of properly coded dynamic array classes right here on SO and other sites.  No need to throw together non-working code and wonder what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
char ch[n+1];
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
`cin>>ch[i];
ch[n] = '\0';
cout<<ch<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at what char *s = new... is initialising. It is not the same as the location that s[i] refers to.

Actually it's wrong for two reasons -- one, char *s is a new declaration within the scope of the for loop, and two because it is not indexed by i.

I think you need s[i] = new char[10] without the char declaration, because s is a double pointer, so s[i] is already a pointer.

Apologies for so many edits, its too late at night....

Answer (score 1):

By using a cin to a char array, you can easily get in trouble, with buffer overrun, as you can see on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642881/194717

You can do something like the code below, but note that a clean way to do this task is to use **vector** and **string**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of words:";
    cin >> n;

    //vector<string> list(n);
    vector<char[100]> list(n);

    // Request from user the words
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> list[i];

    // Display the list
    //for each (string word in list)
    //  cout << word << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << list[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```